# Defective package uninstalled some apps from Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, software-uninstall

I have downloaded a package `gametreelinux`, which I tried to install but failed. It uninstalled the Ubuntu Software Center, System Settings, and maybe other things too. How do I restore these? (I've already re-installed Ubuntu Software Center.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should install any desktop package missing:

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```